# Typescript - @types/uniqid - Problems using namespace and require("uniqid")

Tags: typescript

After installing *@types/uniqid* `npm install --save @types/uniqid` to use in a class I have a problem when instantiating this class with new.

If I put at the top of the page `import uniqid = require("uniqid");` to use `this.id = uniqid();` it's impossible to instanciate the class in the controller file (like `let movie = new Models.Movie();`).
If I don't use `'uniqid'` the controller file will find the correct namespace `Models` and class `Movie`.

Someone have the solution? Thnks a lot

Kind regards

### Code in Movie file

```
import uniqid = require("uniqid"); // Problem I think is here

namespace Models {

    export class Movie 
    {        
        id: string;
        title: string;
        poster: string;

        constructor(title:string, poster:string, id?: string) 
        {
            this.id = uniqid();
            this.title = title;
            this.poster = poster;
        }
    }
}
```

### Code in Controller file

```
///<reference path="../Models/Movie.ts" />
///<reference path="../Contracts/IApiService.ts" />
///<reference path="../../Infrastructure/Api/Api.ts" />

namespace Controller {

    export class MovieController implements Contract.ExternalApiData {


        public ShowAllPopularMovies(data:any)
        {
           let movie = new Models.Movie('something','string'); // Problem here, controller file does not find Movie class
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `import * as uniqId from 'uniqid';` instead of your current import.

Comment: Does not work, you will get `Cannot call a namespace` when compiling ...